# What do "a" and "..." before "interface{}" in the Golang doc mean?

Tags: function, go, interface

In the official documentation, codes like the following appear often.

```
func Printf(format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
```

what are `a` and `...` mean respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is a variable, like any other. `...` is a way to grab many arguments into a slice.

It could be written as:

```
func Printf(format string, a []interface{}) (n int, err error)
```

but then you'd have to call it like this:

```
Printf("", []interface{1,2,3})
```

rather than like this

```
Printf("", 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks Filip :) ! I should have studied Slice in advance.